# "Content Conversion failed" at Office365 when importing ICS-file

Tags: calendar, icalendar

I'm getting "Content Conversion failed" -error message every time when trying to import .ICS -file to my 365 Outlook Calendar.

I'm using my own Java app to generate the file but also tried generate file with ICS-event maker generator found on web at http://apps.marudot.com/ical/

My ICS-file looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//www.marudot.com//iCal Event Maker
X-WR-CALNAME:Exams
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20160609T221559Z
UID:20160609T221559Z-11883410@marudot.com
DTSTART;TZID="Etc/GMT+2":20160831T120000
DTEND;TZID="Etc/GMT+2":20160831T140000
SUMMARY:Biologiy exam
LOCATION:ICT-B1034
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Same ICS-file seems to work fine in the Google Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Your iCalendar file is missing a `VTIMEZONE` component that contains the timezone definition for "Etc/EMT+2".

Alternatively, you could try prepending the `TZID` parameter with a `/` to indicate that it's an Olson timezone ID and that it does not have a `VTIMEZONE` component, like so:

```
DTSTART;TZID="/Etc/GMT+2":20160831T120000
```